# Constrained optimization problem using Largange multipliers: ellipsoid collision detection and response

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-forms, collision-detection

This one is purely for the mathematics so the result is far less important than the method itself.

My task is to implement a fast and efficient ellipsoid collision detection and response algorithm. Having done my literature research, I realized that the method outlined by Rimon and Boyd is probably the best for what I need to implement.

Here is the problem: An ellipsoid is a three dimensional generalization of an ellipse. It is a quadratic surface defined by the equation

\begin{equation*}
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} = 1
\end{equation*}

In its quadratic form, it can be written as

\begin{equation*}
\textbf{(x - a)}^T A \textbf{(x - a)} = 1
\end{equation*}

where **A** is a symmetric positive definite diagonal matrix composed of the inverse squares of the semi-axes lengths and **a** is the centre point vector of the ellipsoid. This ellipsoid is then represented by $\varepsilon (A,a)$

**Given**:   If $\textbf{(x - a)}^T A \textbf{(x - a)} < 1$ for $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ then this point lies within the ellipsoid. If $\textbf{(x - a)}^T A \textbf{(x - a)} > 1$ then the point lies outside of it. This is therefore a good margin function to form a minimization problem with.

**Constraint** :   The point of collision (or as is most frequently the case, overlap) must lie on the other ellipsoid as well. For convenience, let us call the first ellipsoid $\varepsilon_1(A, a)$ and the second one $\varepsilon_2(B, b)$.

**Lagrange multiplier formulation** 
$L(\textbf{x}, \lambda) = \textbf{(x - a)}^T A \textbf{(x - a)} + \lambda \left( \textbf{(x - b)}^T B \textbf{(x - b)} - 1 \right)$

The problem is to perform constrained minimization of the above formulation. Minimum checking is simply done by inserting the real values into the margin and comparing.

\begin{equation}
\nabla_{\textbf{x}, \lambda} L(\textbf{x}, \lambda) = 0
\end{equation}

If simply expanded, this turns out to be a sextic (Lord save the God!) equation which can needless to say scarcely be implemented on a computer. There is no guaranteed solution, let alone a closed form.

However, this can apparently be turned into an eigenvalue problem. Which means I could then use the power method and be done with it, although I must say I fear this because the power method is notoriously hard to plan the convergence of.

Could anybody here help me in trying to make it an eigenvalue problem?

Cheers,
Nitin